# Image on half of screen and another half buttons

Tags: android

May be is little newbie question but how to put listview buttons under the image ... bottom half of screen? Now half of the screen(upper half) is with image. I want to put 2-3 buttons under the image but when I put them they go above the image. I use this xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"

    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/food" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Which I take from another thread. If I put Buttons outside `<RelativeLayout>` they go behind image and hidden.

Comment: i would suggest you to use LinearLayout.ie first split a LinearLayout into two LinearLayouts, then put the image in the first LinearLayout and the buttons in the next LinearLayout..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:weightSum="1"
     android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" 
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/food" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In this way there is a little gap between the image and top bar of the app. Do you know how to stick it to the top bar ie header?

Comment: @IvanPetrov Remove `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` and use `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` or something like that. There are different scale types available for ImageView http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html depending on how you want to handle it

Comment: `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` is already there. You can see it in `<ImageView`, I've also tried to add `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` but doesn't change anything

Comment: @IvanPetrov remove adjustViewBounds :) It is adjusting the bounds of your image view to match that of your image. You want your image to scale to match the bounds of your view.

Comment: Yes, that way is up to the top bar. :) Thank's

Answer (score 0):

As i mentioned in my comment, use `LinearLayout`. ie first split a `LinearLayout` into two `LinearLayout`s, then put the image in the first `LinearLayout` and the buttons in the next `LinearLayout`..

This is how you can divide a `LinearLayout` into two equal `LinearLayout`s

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
  <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Add your image in the first half, ie in the first `LinearLayout` and the buttons in the other one..

ie, do it like this..

```
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
     <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/food" />
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Doing it like this makes your app responsive, ie will fit for all the screen sizes. Check it out..

Comment: Thank's for answer. Got his error 26 times `Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix`

Comment: Add `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` to your topmost Linear Layout..

Comment: Yes, I've tried it with `xmlns...` and I got this errors + `error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix`